# unable to use Font Awesome Icons in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome icons in my app but only some of them work while others give an error and show up as a question mark.

For example, these work:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

            <Icon
              name="user"
              style={styles.userIcon}
              size={moderateScale(20)}
            />
            <Icon name="star" size={moderateScale(13)} />
```

But this does not:

```
<View>
          <Icon name="smoking" color="green"></Icon>
        </View>
```

Even though all of these icons are present here in this directory:

https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=smoking

Secondly, how can I use the `light` version of an icon? For example, the user icon that I am using is filled. How can I change it to the light one as shown in the directory search? Both of them have same names.

Comment: Instead of using FontAwesome directly with React Native you should try react-native-fontawesome, that is their recomendation. It will make your life much easier.

Here is the link of the documentation: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome

Answer (score 2):

There is this [page](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) to look at the icons that `react-native-vector-icons` has. You can clearly see that smoking icon is not part of FontAwesome. In order to use it, you have to use FontAwesome5.

On the other hand, for the outlined version you need to look for its name variant. For example, for using an outlined (or light as you refer to it) variant of the star icon, you gotta use `star-o`